# Automatize .msi installation in AKS Windows node

Tags: windows, kubernetes, installation, windows-installer

I am having a problem and need help, in my job I was commissioned to automate the installation of windows exporter (https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter) in an AKS Windows node pool, initially I thought of automating the Installation through a Daemonset, I found that there is the possibility to execute commands on the host from a linux container on a linux host but I would like to do the same from a windows container to the windows host, is there any possibility of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

From [Adding a Kubernetes/Docker config](https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter/pull/581#issuecomment-670252750):

> I don't think that you can achieve that by running the wmi-exporter
> inside the pod. reason being that Windows does not support privilege
> container so you can not run wmi-exporter in the node context.
>
> You have to run the wmi-exporter.exe on the node to get the node
> metrics. If you want to run it through K8s then you can use the Wins
> (https://github.com/rancher/wins) to run the process on the node
> through container. but it adds the dependency of running wins service
> on each Windows node beforehand.